# Find top performing keywords (clicks) based on the location

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads

I'm trying to connect the keywords used in Google Ads with the location. Basically find the locations for the clicks/impressions for the used keywords in the campaigns. How to connect them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Create campaign
- Add keywords
- [Target campaign to location](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1722043)

Or did you mean something other?